# How to list all folders in a parameter of a Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to build dinamically a parameter of a pipeline; in particular, the values of the parameter should be all the names of the folders at depth 1 from where the yaml file of the pipeline is located.
After that, I would like to build dinamically another parameter, where the values should be all the file names found in the previously selected folder.

Thanks a lot

I tried with a script in a task, without result.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for a pipeline cannot be templatized or based on a REST API call or other metadata query, except for a few predefined ones, such as environments or branches.

Other than the predefined ones, only statically defined parameters are supported:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/parameters-parameter?view=azure-pipelines

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write a PowerShell script to get the file or folder names, not mean the [Runtime parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#parameter-data-types) in Azure DevOps pipeline, please refer this script.

```
# Get the names of all folders in the current directory
$Parameter1 = Get-ChildItem -Directory | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Get the names of all files in all folders in the current directory
$Parameter2 = Get-ChildItem -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $folder = $_
    Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}

#A string containing the names of all files, separated by commas and spaces
$Parameter2 = $Parameter2 -join ", "

# Output the values of Parameter1 and Parameter4
Write-Output "Parameter1: $Parameter1"
Write-Output "Parameter2: $Parameter2"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use CMD task to call tree command in Microsoft-Hosted windows agent to get the folder structure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).